# How do I reload a proxy automatic configuration file (.pac)?

Tags: gnome, http-proxy

I have a server set up that I want to use as an automatic proxy server per rules in a `.pac` file.  I'm troubleshooting different changes to the `.pac` file but I'm not sure if my web browser/OS is reloading the `.pac` file after each change.  How can I force the client to re-download the `.pac` file or at least ensure it's using the latest version?

I'm using Fedora 19 and configure proxy settings through the Gnome settings GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a working .pac file and experimenting, I found that the file was re-downloaded when I killed the web browser and re-opened it again.  Editing the field in the network configuration dialog did not cause any GET requests to the `.pac` file on my server.

Answer (score 1):

If you disconnect from, and then reconnect to, the network, the system will have to detect your new network settings. Presumably this must include the proxy settings.